# Cross threaded hole on seat rail of VW. How to get the original size screw back in?

Tags: interior, polo

So long story short, someone managed to cross thread one of the seat rail bolts while removing and reinstalling the seats. They then simply tapped a larger hole and used a larger bolt to fix the problem.

I would like (purely out of OCD) to go back the factory bolt. How do I make the hole the correct size again? And also, anyone know what the specifications are for the seat rail bolts on a VW Polo 6R?

Comment: This was cross-posted over on DIY.SE and got more attention: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/133981/43874

Comment: your first concern should be that the repair is as good strength-wise as the original.  You should not risk degrading the repair (assuming it was done well to begin with) just to satisfy your ocd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities that come to mind straight away:

One use a helicoil to provide the size you want, which means drilling out to a larger size and fitting an insert - sounds like this has been done, but is it to the correct size?

Two is to remove the damaged nut and re-weld a new one into place...

I would live with the "new" bolt as is, then my next option would be to do the helicoil...

Comment: What has been done is use one of those self tapping bolts of a slightly larger size. No Helicoil was used. I wonder if something simple like epoxy won't work? You are of course right that I should just live with it but it'd be nice to go back to factory bolts

Comment: So, as I said use a helicoil to get back to the original size...